# Using node.js to display helpscout metrics

Tags: node.js

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I would like to use metrics-helpscout to bring back data that I can use for a dashboard.  I am not having any luck.  This is also my first time using node.js so I apologize in advance.

Here is what I have tried so far.
Following the instructions on github I used npm to install segmentio/metrics, metrics-helpscout and metrics-express.

I created a file called metrics.js and added this...

```
var Metrics = require('metrics');
var expressMetrics  = require('metrics-express');
var helpscout = require('metrics-helpscout');
var express = require('metrics-express/node_modules/express');

var app = express();

console.log('start' );

var zzz = Metrics()
  .every('1m', helpscout('myapi-key', ['my-mailbox-id']))
  .on('helpscout active tickets', function (metric) {
         console.log('helpscout update:' + metric.latest() );
      }); 

var xxx = Metrics()
  .every('1m', helpscout('myapi-key', ['my-mailbox-id']));

  var date = new Date();
  var val = 3;
  var key = 'test';
  var ddd = Metrics().set(key, val, date);

   app.use('/', expressMetrics(xxx))
    .listen(7002);
```

I then started the file by running node metrics.js
I opened a browser and hit the url and port and I just got back

[]

On the metrics express page example i used the var xxx.  I thought I would get back a list of all the supported metrics.  I then tested just using my var ddd and it did return my value.  I am sure I am missing something or a lot.

Any help is appreciated.

Just in case it matters I am using ArchLinux.

Answer (score 0):

Welp I figured it out.  I generated a new API key and it worked.